# Reading fortran unformatted arrays with python without numpy

Tags: python, binary, fortran

I am quite new to Python. I am trying to read an unformatted Fortran file by using Python. However, I would like to structure the elements read into arrays. I prepared for you a sample to help you understand my problem. Here below you can find a Fortran writer which writes three integers and then a line with three double precision elements.

```
    program writer
    integer :: dummy,dummy2,dummy3
    double precision,dimension(3) :: dummy_double
          dummy=1
          dummy2=2
          dummy3=3
          dummy_double(1)=4.23e0
          dummy_double(2)=5.4e0
          dummy_double(3)=7.61e0

          open(100,file="binary",form="unformatted",convert="little_endian")
          write(100) dummy
          write(100) dummy2
          write(100) dummy3
          write(100) dummy_double(1:3)
          close(100)
          end
```

I now want to read this file with Python without using numpy. I am aware of the INTEGER*4 at the end and beginning of each record. I skip the first 4 bits at the beginning of the file, then I read the first integer, then I skip 8 bits (end+begin) and so on. No separator is written in a same sequence, that is the double precision are not separated by an INTEGER*4 (correct me if I am wrong..). I am writing to you because I am not able to read the last line, with the 3 double precision records. I would like to store them in the `comp[3]` array.

```
import struct
with open("binary", "rb") as f:
#    while True:
        dummy = f.read(4)
        print "dummy=",struct.unpack('i', f.read(4))[0]
        dummy = f.read(8)
        print "dummy2=",struct.unpack('i', f.read(4))[0]
        dummy = f.read(8)
        print "dummy3=",struct.unpack('i', f.read(4))[0]
        comp = [0] * 3
        print "length=",len(comp)
        dummy = f.read(8)
        comp=struct.unpack('<d', f.read(8))[0:2]
        print "comp=",comp[0],comp[1],comp[2]
```

The error I am getting is the following:

```
$carlo: python Script_Library.py
dummy= 1
dummy2= 2
dummy3= 3
length= 3
comp= 4.23000001907
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Script_Library.py", line 14, in <module>
    print "comp=",comp[0],comp[1],comp[2]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Integers are correctly read as well as the first double precision elements. However, they are not correctly stored. Would you please correct the parts of the script which are not working?

Comment: Which Fortran compiler do you use? 32-bit or 64-bit? The record markers are not that standardized as you appear to imply.

Comment: Try to replace the last line of your code with `print "comp="+comp[0]+comp[1]+comp[2]`. I guess the problem is that Python reads your code like `(print "comp="), comp[0], comp[1], comp[2]`. I'm not sure because I haven't write in Python2 for a long time and Python3 has different print syntax. But give it a try.

Comment: Also the line is not 3 double precision records but one record with 3 double precision numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using both ifort and gfortran 64 bits and the error message doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks Alissa. I gave it a try without success:                                   
print +comp[0]+comp[1]+comp[2]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Try to use `comp=struct.unpack('<ddd', f.read(24))`. `comp` will become a tuple with three numbers. `struct.unpack()` always returns tuple, even if there is only a single element.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is solved thanks to **durasm**.

I report here the working codes:

```
program writer
integer :: dummy,dummy2,dummy3
double precision,dimension(3) :: dummy_double
          dummy=1
          dummy2=2
          dummy3=3
          dummy_double(1)=4.23e0
          dummy_double(2)=5.4e0
          dummy_double(3)=7.61e0

          open(100,file="binary",form="unformatted",convert="little_endian")
          write(100) dummy
          write(100) dummy2
          write(100) dummy3
          write(100) dummy_double(1:3)
          close(100)
end
```

Here below you can find the corrected script. First of all, no need to allocate `comp`. Then, we have three double precision records to read, equivalent to `24 bits` and three times `ddd`.

```
import struct
with open("binary", "rb") as f:
        dummy = f.read(4)
        print "dummy=",struct.unpack('i', f.read(4))[0]
        dummy = f.read(8)
        print "dummy2=",struct.unpack('i', f.read(4))[0]
        dummy = f.read(8)
        print "dummy3=",struct.unpack('i', f.read(4))[0]
        dummy = f.read(8)
        comp=struct.unpack('<ddd', f.read(24))
        print "comp=",comp[0],comp[1],comp[2]
```

And the result:

```
$carlo: python Script_Library.py
dummy= 1
dummy2= 2
dummy3= 3
comp= 4.23000001907 5.40000009537 7.61000013351
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with this line:

```
comp=struct.unpack('<d', f.read(8))[0:2]
```

If you index a list with something `[a:b]` it will return a list of values from `a` to `b-1`:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4][0:2]
[1, 2]
```

So after this line, `comp` is a list/array with two values, not three. So `comp[2]` will fail with an index out of range error.

Comment: Access='stream' is meant to be  compatible with other languages.